# RXJS: alternately combine elements of streams

Tags: rxjs

I'd like to alternately combine elements of multiple streams:

```
var print = console.log.bind(console);

var s1 = Rx.Observable.fromArray([1, 1, 5]);
var s2 = Rx.Observable.fromArray([2, 9]);
var s3 = Rx.Observable.fromArray([3, 4, 6, 7, 8]);

alternate(s1, s2, s3).subscribe(print); // 1, 2, 3, 1, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

How looks the function definition of `alternate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a value (for example `undefined`) that is not emitted by the source observables, this solution works:

```js
var concat = Rx.Observable.concat;
var repeat = Rx.Observable.repeat;
var zipArray = Rx.Observable.zipArray;
var fromArray = Rx.Observable.fromArray;

var print = console.log.bind(console);

var s1 = fromArray([1, 1, 5]);
var s2 = fromArray([2, 9]);
var s3 = fromArray([3, 4, 6, 7, 8]);

alternate(s1, s2, s3).subscribe(print);

function alternate() {
    var sources = Array.slice(arguments).map(function(s) {
        return concat(s, repeat(undefined))
    });
    return zipArray(sources)
            .map(function(values) {
                return values.filter(function(x) {
                    return x !== undefined;
                });
            }).takeWhile(function(values) {
                return values.length > 0;
            }).concatMap(function (list) { return fromArray(list); })
}
```

Same example in ES6:

```js
const {concat, repeat, zipArray, fromArray} = Rx.Observable;

var print = console.log.bind(console);

var s1 = fromArray([1, 1, 5]);
var s2 = fromArray([2, 9]);
var s3 = fromArray([3, 4, 6, 7, 8]);

alternate(s1, s2, s3).subscribe(print);

function alternate(...sources) {
    return zipArray(sources.map( (s) => concat(s, repeat(undefined)) ))
            .map((values) => values.filter( (x) => x !== undefined ))
            .takeWhile( (values) => values.length > 0)
            .concatMap( (list) => fromArray(list) )
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use zip and concatMap when working on observables that were created from arrays (as in your example), or zip and flatMap when working on observables that are inherently asynchronous.

```
Rx.Observable
  .zip(s1, s2, s3, function(x,y,z) { return [x,y,z]; })
  .concatMap(function (list) { return Rx.Observable.from(list); })
  .subscribe(print); // 1, 2, 3, 1, 9, 4
```

Notice that this doesn't proceed anymore once one of the source observables completes. That's because `zip` is strictly "balanced" and it waits until all the sources have a matching event. What you want is a somewhat loose version of zip when dealing with completed sources.